# Rewrite URL with two parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this project structure:

/dir/main/include

In the main folder is the index.php.
In the include folder is the verify.php.

When a sql query successfully inserted, a email will be send. (index.php)

In my index.php I send the mail with the following url:

```
<a href='http://domain.com/dir/main/include/verify.php?user_id=$user_id&tokenCode=$tokenCode'>Click here.</a>
```

Now, the verify.php will be called. I get the 'user_id' and the 'tokenCode' with:

```
$user_id   = $_GET['user_id'];
$tokenCode = $_GET['tokenCode'];
```

Well, the question is:
Firstly, How can I do this with .htaccess? 
Secondly, where should the .htaccess located?

The url will generated with:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/../db_config.php';

    // Create connection

    $conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

    // Check connection

    if ($conn->connect_error)
        {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }
        // Request type is Register new user
        $username     = $_POST['username'];
        $email    = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];



    $sql = "SELECT email from user WHERE email = '$email'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $sql2 = "SELECT username from user WHERE username = '$username'";
    $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            // user existed 
            $response["error"]     = TRUE;
            $response["error_msg"] = "email already existed";
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else if($result2->num_rows > 0){

                // user is already existed - error response
                $response["error"]     = TRUE;
                $response["error_msg"] = "username already existed";
                echo json_encode($response);
        } else {

                $uuser_id               = uniqid('', true);
        $tokenCode          = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 25);
        $salt      = **hided**;
        $salt      = substr($salt, 0, 10);
        $encrypted = **hided**
        $hash      = array(
            "salt" => $salt,
            "encrypted" => $encrypted
        );
        $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
        $salt               = $hash["salt"]; // salt

    $sql = "INSERT INTO user(username, email, tokenCode, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES('$username', '$email', '$tokenCode', '$encrypted_password', '$salt', NOW())";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
        // check for successful store
        if ($result) {
            $user_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id = $user_id";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
            {

            // temp user array

                    $response["error"]              = FALSE;
                    $response["user_id"]            = $row["user_id"];
                    $response["user"]["username"]       = $row["username"];
                    $response["user"]["email"]      = $row["email"];
                    $response["user"]["created_at"] = $row["created_at"];
            }
                    echo json_encode($response);

           $message = "                 
                        Hello $username,
                        <br /><br />
                        !<br/>
                        To complete please , just click following link<br/>
                        <br /><br />
                        <a href='http://domain.com/dir/main/include/verify.php?user_id=$user_id&tokenCode=$tokenCode'>Click here.</a>
                        <br /><br />
                        Thanks";



        }
```

Comment: this doesn't related to php

Comment: Why? I want to hide the php parameters?

Comment: what! you are appending value to url and getting them as post how come?

Comment: If you don't have the user ID and token code in the URL, where is the script supposed to get them from?

Comment: @Barmar that is a generated verification url, read comments on my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/39706889/4977144

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The `RewriteRule`:**

put the following line in the `.htaccess` file in the root dir,

```
RewriteRule ^verify/id(.*)/token(.*)$ dir/main/include/verify.php?user_id=$1&tokenCode=$2 [NC,L]
```

**Update:** Change the `href=""` in this part:

```
          $message = "                 
                    Hello $username,
                    <br /><br />
                    !<br/>
                    To complete please , just click following link<br/>
                    <br /><br />
                    <a href='http://domain.com/dir/main/include/verify.php?user_id=$user_id&tokenCode=$tokenCode'>Click here.</a>
                    <br /><br />
                    Thanks";
```

**to:**

```
       $message = "                 
                    Hello $username,
                    <br /><br />
                    !<br/>
                    To complete please , just click following link<br/>
                    <br /><br />
                    <a href='http://domain.com/verify/id$user_id/token$tokenCode'>Click here.</a>
                    <br /><br />
                    Thanks";
```

**summery:** that means when user click on that link, the request will go to `http://domain.com/dir/main/include/verify.php`, but the user will see in the browser url bar `http://domain.com/verify/id123456/token123456abc`

**Make sure** you add the `RewriteRule` above to the `.htaccess` file in the root directory.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer.
I am sending a mail with this url:


      <a href='http://domain.com/dir/main/include/verify.php?user_id=$user_id&tokenCode=$tokenCode'>Click HERE to Activate :-)</a>

and please have a look at my edit, I am using GET parameters. :)

Comment: what actually do you want to do? the full story?

Comment: oh, thats changes the story i can provide you a solution but it may be a little hard to understand, also it may cause a redirect loop that ends with #500 error or connection timeout, i'll edit my answer

Comment: if you got any errors or don't understand some part, ill explain it :)

Comment: I didn't get it so well, so it doesn't work so far for me..

I tried to explain it clearly. Hope you can understand my problem.

Thanks so far for help :-)

Comment: @blueman3399 please post the code that generates the verify url

Comment: I added the generation :)

Comment: Now, i become:
The requested URL /verify/id77/tokenWpdSQmAIXlegPtO0TVqnUJyzs was not found on this server.

Comment: did you added the `RewriteRule` in the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: My .htaccess file is in the /dir folder an looks like this:

RewriteRule ^verify/id(.*)/token(.*)$ dir/main/include/verify.php?user_id=$1&tokenCode=$2 [NC,L]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124316/discussion-between-xyuri-and-blueman3399).